# How to keep my app name in iTunes Connect before it will be removed?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I received message from iTunes connect:
"You have not yet uploaded a binary for your app, "MyGameName". Our records show that this app was created in iTunes Connect more than 173 days ago.
If you do not upload a binary for your app by 29 June 2013 (Pacific Time), it will be deleted from iTunes Connect. The app name will then be available for another developer to use."

If I upload 25 June and Apple won't review a game before 29 June. Game's name will be rejected or not?

Comment: Be a good citizen and release the name if you are not going to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When apple deletes it after the 180 days, you will get a email that it was removed. When you get the email just go to itunes connect and add a new app and you can get your name back.

Comment: You mean delete the whole project from iTunes connect??? But if I delete my App from itunes connect. I couldn't take this name again: Here is what Apple says on deleting app:

"Are you sure you want to delete this app?  Deleting the app permanently removes it from iTunes Connect, along with all associated In-App Purchases. The App Name and SKU can not be reused, even after the app is deleted. If you have uploaded a binary or set up this app for the iAd Network, your Bundle ID can not be reused either."

Comment: No no no do not delete, you wait until apple delete it after the 180 days are up. then you re add it

Comment: You mean just re-create new project with the same app's name. Right?

Comment: No. when Apple deletes your app after the 180 days are up, which you got the email saying the 180 are almost up. Just recreate the app when it is delete buy apple

Comment: The apple docs say you can't use the same name twice, but others can. This prevents name squatting.

Comment: Gareth is correct. After 180 days it will be made available to all other developers except you. You can never get the name back if you delete the app or let it expire.

"If you do not deliver a binary before the 180-day deadline, your app is deleted from iTunes Connect. As a result of this deletion, your app
name can be used by another developer and you cannot reuse the app name, SKU or bundle ID."

Answer (score 3):

Here's a dumb way to trick apple. Upload your game binary. Don't worry if its complete or not. Once upload to iTunes is successful, wait a few mins till its status changed to "Waiting for Review", then click on the "Binary" link and hit "Reject this binary". Walla! Apple will not bug you again.

Once you are ready to upload your fully completed game, click on "ready to upload binary" link and your app status will change to "waiting for binary upload"

Comment: @StevenKoposov if my answer helped then please check mark it ...  I need those brownie points :-)